Translating a part of the Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem into first order logic
The part of the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem that I want to translate into first order logic is the following: For every signature A, every infinite A-structure B, and every infinite cardinal number C, there is an A-structure D, such that D=C.
Is this a correct way of translating it?

A=The property of being a mathematical structure.
B=The property of being infinite
C=The property of being a cardinal number
D=The property of being equal to y
∀x∀y∃z(Ax∧Bx∧By∧Cy→Az∧Bz∧Dz)

Are there other ways of translating it?

Without getting into details, which can come later, the main problem is your formalization is simply not informative, there is no connection between the various terms, to the point that there is no element for you to even start proving it...

The theorem is stated here, I’m pretty sure in first-order logic: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem

@JuliusHamilton It is a meta-theorem about first order theories, since it talks about their models it is not itself expressible in first order logic.
